# Do transactions collect queries to the database or lock it until a commit?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, transactions

Assume this snippet of Hiberante code:

```
session.beginTransaction();
Event event1 = session.load(1);
Event event2 = new Event(2);
event2.setNextEvent(event1);
event2.save();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

My question is, does this work as expected? That is, can I read something from the database, set it on another entity, and then save that entity to the database in a single transaction?

In other words, does beginning the transaction mean "I'll collect all queries to the database, and hold on to them until you tell me to commit them." orr does begin really just mean lock and commit means unlock?

Comment: I don't know about this code specifically (I haven't done anything Transactional in Java), but if inside a general transaction system you can't access changes that you've made (inserts/deletes) then the transactioning process is fundamentally broken :) So I would assume that yes, you can. But I don't know for sure (can you test it?)

Comment: @Jeff: Fixed. Either way, the question still stands with out it. The point is that can successive "calls" be affected by previous ones?

Comment: @Jeremy, I still don't see where you have added a write to the transaction. I will still try to answer below.

Comment: @Jeff: I didnt add a write, I altered my question, as it doesn't really matter what the second statement is, as long as it is being affected by something returned from the first statement.

Comment: @Jeremy, with the reads, I don't think it should matter. Have you tried it with whatever database you are using?

Comment: @Jeff - My concern here is with the ORM. If this type of code is committing each "statement" one by one, then what is the purpose of a transaction? The commit is implicitly done when the method is done executing. So, my assumption is that until the commit happens, the transaction is just collecting statements to call on the database, and when that happens, the ORM replaces proxied objects with their true values. But, can that be "fixed" by filling the proxies and remember where input came from?

Comment: @Jeremy, you're not really "committing" anything - a commit typically refers to a write to a database, but I understand what you're asking. Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @Jeff - I will when I am able to. I am more or less curious about the "magic" that seems to occur that online examples never seem to address. Does Just Work(tm) or am I supposed to know that this really isn't 100% Java and have to deal with a different memory model?

Comment: @Jeff: (a response to your now deleted answer).  'Should a TX see its own updates' is one of the tricky issues in DBMS design.  There are solid grounds for saying that a transaction should see its own updates, but the MVCC systems (such as Oracle) don't make that easy - or even possible.  It often doesn't make a difference; if you don't update the same row multiple times, and don't select the row after you've updated it, then there's no problem.  If your transaction does, then the locking DBMS behave differently from the MVCC DBMS.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for the clarification. I deleted the answer since it can be confusing and varies across DBMS, so didn't want to give an incorrect answer.

Comment: @Jeremy, Jonathan's comment gives some good insight, but in your example, you aren't actually updating the rows, so I would think it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read through your example several times and I cannot see what you are talking about. There are no changes or commits in the code and no indication of whats pending commit and whats not. If this code was was in a typical system making use of an ORM such as hibernate there would be no issue with it that I can see.

Presuming that `a` has not been committed to the database, then `dao.findBar(a)` would still return it because it would be in hibernates caches. Presuming it has been associated with hibernates session in the first place.

`dao.findBar(a)` should return `x`, providing it fits the same criteria as `a`. i.e. that it already exists or has been associated with the hibernate session.

So therefore `dao.findBar(x.getBaz())` should also work presuming the same sort of stuff.

As you can see there is a lot of "presumably's" in the above statements. I doubt you will get a better answer without a clearer question.

A further complication is that your question doesn't mention ORM's, but you talk about them in the comments. Hence my comment assume that situation. If you are not using an ORM and your dao accesses a database directly through JDBC then the answers would be entirely different again - depending on the internal coding of the dao.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that "begin" and "commit" really are just "lock" and "unlock"? And that every call to the database happens exactly when it is requested, instead of them all being grouped together and executed at once?

Comment: No, they are grouped together. Hibernate is smart enough to work out a lot of things like this. Once you has an object associated with a hibernate session, hibernate can return it to you, even if it has not committed it yet to the database. Apple's core data does the same thing.

Comment: Think of it this way, you have players in a football game, those on the field are objects in your program. Those in the change rooms are objects in your database. You have to manage the transfers back and forwards and who interacts with who. Adding an ORM is like adding a bench. You can concentrate on whose is in the game and move them backwards and forwards between the game and bench as necessary, and they can freely interact with each other. The ORM handles the transfers between the change rooms and bench, leaving you to concentrate on the game.

Comment: To answer you edited question, yes you can do that sort of code. It's the ORM's job to group up and sort out the necessary queries to the database based on the objects you set up. Note order does not matter. An ORM for example, will typically perform deletes before additions, regardless of the order you did them. (Unless you tell it otherwise :-) This is one of the reasons ORMs such as hibernate are so popular, they take the stress out of managing database change.